# Type internal stateless functions with flowtype

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

since the last flow update (0.61) feels like I'm living in a nightmare.

Currently I'm struggling to get a simple stateless component to pass flow tests.

Here's my code:

```
function FlexRow (props: PropTypes): ReactElement => {
    function _getRowClasses (): Array<*> => {
        const cssClasses = []

        if (props.xs) {
            cssClasses.push(styles.xs)
        }
        if (props.sm) {
            cssClasses.push(styles.sm)
        }
        if (props.md) {
            cssClasses.push(styles.md)
        }
        if (props.lg) {
            cssClasses.push(styles.lg)
        }
        if (props.xl) {
            cssClasses.push(styles.xl)
        }
        if (props.class) {
            cssClasses.push(props.class)
        }
        return cssClasses
    }

    function _getRowStyles () {
        const cssStyles = {}
        if (props.offset) {
            cssStyles.marginLeft = (props.offset * -1)
            cssStyles.marginRight = (props.offset * -1)
        }
        if (props.inset) {
            cssStyles.paddingLeft = props.inset
            cssStyles.paddingRight = props.inset
        }
        return cssStyles
    }

    return (
        <div className={classNames(styles.flexrow, _getRowClasses())} style={_getRowStyles()}>
            {React.Children.toArray(props.children)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I'm getting a flow error at:

```
function _getRowClasses (): Array<*> => {
```

the error says:
**Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected : (Fatal)**

I tried to look into the docs, but dude, they have the worst documentation ever. So I would appreciate if someone could give me some help.

Peace,
TF

Answer (score 0):

Flow is right: `=>` is unexpected in function definition. Just fix first two rows:

```
function FlexRow (props: PropTypes): ReactElement {  
    function _getRowClasses (): Array<*> {
...
```

Comment: Now I'm getting another error:  
  
On function FlexRow (props: PropTypes): ReactElement { . 
...  
  
On PropTypes -> React element `FlexRow` This type is incompatible with object type.  
On ReactElement -> ReactElement Could not resolve name.  
  
What endless mess :( .

Comment: Please put simple repro [here](https://flow.org/try/) and maybe I'll be able to help you.